# org.gradle.api.InvalidUserCodeException: Querying the mapped value of provider (java.util.Set) before task ... has completed is not supported

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, gradle-plugin, gradle-kotlin-dsl

I upgraded my project to Android Studio Arctic Fox, so I have to upgrade gradle to 7.0.2 and gradle build tool to 7.0.0-beta04.

After synchronizing, I got this warning message in Sync tab:

```
org.gradle.api.InvalidUserCodeException: Querying the mapped value of provider(interface java.util.Set) before task ':myapp:compileDebugUnitTestKotlin' has completed is not supported
    at org.gradle.api.internal.provider.TransformBackedProvider.lambda$beforeRead$0(TransformBackedProvider.java:84)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.file.AbstractFileCollection$ElementsProvider$1.visitProducerTasks(AbstractFileCollection.java:361)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.provider.ValueSupplier$ValueProducer.visitContentProducerTasks(ValueSupplier.java:59)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.provider.TransformBackedProvider.beforeRead(TransformBackedProvider.java:81)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.provider.TransformBackedProvider.calculateOwnValue(TransformBackedProvider.java:63)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.provider.AbstractMinimalProvider.calculateValue(AbstractMinimalProvider.java:103)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.provider.Collectors$ElementsFromCollectionProvider.collectEntries(Collectors.java:216)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.provider.AbstractCollectionProperty$PlusCollector.collectEntries(AbstractCollectionProperty.java:445)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.provider.AbstractCollectionProperty$PlusCollector.collectEntries(AbstractCollectionProperty.java:445)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.provider.AbstractCollectionProperty$CollectingSupplier.calculateValue(AbstractCollectionProperty.java:337)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.provider.AbstractCollectionProperty.calculateValueFrom(AbstractCollectionProperty.java:184)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.provider.AbstractCollectionProperty.calculateValueFrom(AbstractCollectionProperty.java:37)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.provider.AbstractProperty.doCalculateValue(AbstractProperty.java:133)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.provider.AbstractProperty.calculateOwnValue(AbstractProperty.java:127)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.provider.AbstractMinimalProvider.calculateValue(AbstractMinimalProvider.java:103)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.provider.Collectors$ElementsFromCollectionProvider.collectEntries(Collectors.java:216)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.provider.AbstractCollectionProperty$CollectingSupplier.calculateValue(AbstractCollectionProperty.java:337)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.provider.AbstractCollectionProperty.calculateValueFrom(AbstractCollectionProperty.java:184)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.provider.AbstractCollectionProperty.calculateValueFrom(AbstractCollectionProperty.java:37)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.provider.AbstractProperty.doCalculateValue(AbstractProperty.java:133)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.provider.AbstractProperty.calculateOwnValue(AbstractProperty.java:127)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.provider.AbstractMinimalProvider.calculateValue(AbstractMinimalProvider.java:103)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.provider.Collectors$ElementsFromCollectionProvider.collectEntries(Collectors.java:216)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.provider.AbstractCollectionProperty$CollectingSupplier.calculateValue(AbstractCollectionProperty.java:337)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.provider.AbstractCollectionProperty.calculateValueFrom(AbstractCollectionProperty.java:184)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.provider.AbstractCollectionProperty.calculateValueFrom(AbstractCollectionProperty.java:37)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.provider.AbstractProperty.doCalculateValue(AbstractProperty.java:133)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.provider.AbstractProperty.calculateOwnValue(AbstractProperty.java:127)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.provider.AbstractMinimalProvider.get(AbstractMinimalProvider.java:84)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.provider.ProviderResolutionStrategy$2.resolve(ProviderResolutionStrategy.java:33)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.file.collections.ProviderBackedFileCollection.visitChildren(ProviderBackedFileCollection.java:63)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.file.CompositeFileCollection.visitContents(CompositeFileCollection.java:119)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.file.AbstractFileCollection.visitStructure(AbstractFileCollection.java:330)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.file.CompositeFileCollection.lambda$visitContents$0(CompositeFileCollection.java:119)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.file.collections.UnpackingVisitor.add(UnpackingVisitor.java:74)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.file.collections.DefaultConfigurableFileCollection$UnresolvedItemsCollector.visitContents(DefaultConfigurableFileCollection.java:372)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.file.collections.DefaultConfigurableFileCollection.visitChildren(DefaultConfigurableFileCollection.java:284)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.file.CompositeFileCollection.visitContents(CompositeFileCollection.java:119)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.file.AbstractFileCollection.getFiles(AbstractFileCollection.java:130)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.tooling.builder.ExternalTestsModelBuilderImpl.getPaths(ExternalTestsModelBuilderImpl.groovy:94)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor813.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:107)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.StaticMetaMethodSite$StaticMetaMethodSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.invoke(StaticMetaMethodSite.java:149)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.StaticMetaMethodSite.callStatic(StaticMetaMethodSite.java:100)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callStatic(AbstractCallSite.java:231)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.tooling.builder.ExternalTestsModelBuilderImpl.getClassesDirs(ExternalTestsModelBuilderImpl.groovy:81)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.tooling.builder.ExternalTestsModelBuilderImpl.access$0(ExternalTestsModelBuilderImpl.groovy)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.tooling.builder.ExternalTestsModelBuilderImpl$_getMapping_closure1.doCall(ExternalTestsModelBuilderImpl.groovy:41)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor811.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:107)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:323)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.ClosureMetaClass.invokeMethod(ClosureMetaClass.java:263)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1035)
    at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:412)
    at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:428)
    at org.gradle.util.ClosureBackedAction.execute(ClosureBackedAction.java:71)
    at org.gradle.util.ConfigureUtil.configureTarget(ConfigureUtil.java:154)
    at org.gradle.util.ConfigureUtil.configureSelf(ConfigureUtil.java:130)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask.configure(AbstractTask.java:616)
    at org.gradle.api.DefaultTask.configure(DefaultTask.java:307)
    at org.gradle.api.DefaultTask.configure(DefaultTask.java:44)
    at org.gradle.util.ConfigureUtil.configure(ConfigureUtil.java:103)
    at org.gradle.util.ConfigureUtil$WrappedConfigureAction.execute(ConfigureUtil.java:166)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.collections.CollectionFilter$1.execute(CollectionFilter.java:59)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.DefaultDomainObjectCollection.all(DefaultDomainObjectCollection.java:163)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.DefaultRealizableTaskCollection.all(DefaultRealizableTaskCollection.java:224)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.DefaultDomainObjectCollection.withType(DefaultDomainObjectCollection.java:205)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.DefaultDomainObjectCollection.withType(DefaultDomainObjectCollection.java:211)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.tooling.builder.ExternalTestsModelBuilderImpl.getMapping(ExternalTestsModelBuilderImpl.groovy:40)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.tooling.builder.ExternalTestsModelBuilderImpl.buildAll(ExternalTestsModelBuilderImpl.groovy:29)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.tooling.internal.ExtraModelBuilder.buildAll(ExtraModelBuilder.java:115)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.tooling.internal.ExtraModelBuilder.buildAll(ExtraModelBuilder.java:80)
    at org.gradle.tooling.provider.model.internal.DefaultToolingModelBuilderRegistry$BuilderWithParameter.build(DefaultToolingModelBuilderRegistry.java:192)
    at org.gradle.tooling.provider.model.internal.DefaultToolingModelBuilderRegistry$LockSingleProjectBuilder.lambda$build$0(DefaultToolingModelBuilderRegistry.java:211)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProjectStateRegistry$ProjectStateImpl.lambda$withProjectLock$3(DefaultProjectStateRegistry.java:310)
    at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService.withLocks(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:213)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProjectStateRegistry$ProjectStateImpl.withProjectLock(DefaultProjectStateRegistry.java:310)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProjectStateRegistry$ProjectStateImpl.fromMutableState(DefaultProjectStateRegistry.java:291)
    at org.gradle.tooling.provider.model.internal.DefaultToolingModelBuilderRegistry$LockSingleProjectBuilder.build(DefaultToolingModelBuilderRegistry.java:211)
    at org.gradle.tooling.provider.model.internal.DefaultToolingModelBuilderRegistry$BuildOperationWrappingBuilder$1.call(DefaultToolingModelBuilderRegistry.java:246)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:200)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:195)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$3.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:75)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$3.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:68)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:153)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:68)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.call(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:62)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.lambda$call$2(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:76)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.UnmanagedBuildOperationWrapper.callWithUnmanagedSupport(UnmanagedBuildOperationWrapper.java:54)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:76)
    at org.gradle.tooling.provider.model.internal.DefaultToolingModelBuilderRegistry$BuildOperationWrappingBuilder.build(DefaultToolingModelBuilderRegistry.java:243)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.DefaultBuildController.getModel(DefaultBuildController.java:102)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.ParameterAwareBuildControllerAdapter.getModel(ParameterAwareBuildControllerAdapter.java:39)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.UnparameterizedBuildController.getModel(UnparameterizedBuildController.java:113)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.NestedActionAwareBuildControllerAdapter.getModel(NestedActionAwareBuildControllerAdapter.java:31)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.UnparameterizedBuildController.findModel(UnparameterizedBuildController.java:97)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.NestedActionAwareBuildControllerAdapter.findModel(NestedActionAwareBuildControllerAdapter.java:31)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.UnparameterizedBuildController.findModel(UnparameterizedBuildController.java:81)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.NestedActionAwareBuildControllerAdapter.findModel(NestedActionAwareBuildControllerAdapter.java:31)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.model.ProjectImportAction$MyBuildController.findModel(ProjectImportAction.java:542)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.model.ClassSetImportModelProvider.populateProjectModels(ClassSetImportModelProvider.java:39)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.model.ProjectImportAction.addProjectModels(ProjectImportAction.java:201)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.model.ProjectImportAction.execute(ProjectImportAction.java:114)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.model.ProjectImportAction.execute(ProjectImportAction.java:41)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.InternalBuildActionAdapter.execute(InternalBuildActionAdapter.java:64)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.AbstractClientProvidedBuildActionRunner$ActionRunningListener.runAction(AbstractClientProvidedBuildActionRunner.java:134)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.AbstractClientProvidedBuildActionRunner$ActionRunningListener.buildFinished(AbstractClientProvidedBuildActionRunner.java:119)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor766.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:36)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
    at org.gradle.internal.event.DefaultListenerManager$ListenerDetails.dispatch(DefaultListenerManager.java:398)
    at org.gradle.internal.event.DefaultListenerManager$ListenerDetails.dispatch(DefaultListenerManager.java:380)
    at org.gradle.internal.event.AbstractBroadcastDispatch.dispatch(AbstractBroadcastDispatch.java:61)
    at org.gradle.internal.event.DefaultListenerManager$EventBroadcast$ListenerDispatch.dispatch(DefaultListenerManager.java:368)
    at org.gradle.internal.event.DefaultListenerManager$EventBroadcast$ListenerDispatch.dispatch(DefaultListenerManager.java:355)
    at org.gradle.internal.event.AbstractBroadcastDispatch.dispatch(AbstractBroadcastDispatch.java:43)
    at org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch$SingletonDispatch.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:245)
    at org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch$SingletonDispatch.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:157)
    at org.gradle.internal.event.AbstractBroadcastDispatch.dispatch(AbstractBroadcastDispatch.java:61)
    at org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch$CompositeDispatch.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:346)
    at org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch$CompositeDispatch.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:249)
    at org.gradle.internal.event.ListenerBroadcast.dispatch(ListenerBroadcast.java:141)
    at org.gradle.internal.event.ListenerBroadcast.dispatch(ListenerBroadcast.java:37)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ProxyDispatchAdapter$DispatchingInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyDispatchAdapter.java:94)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy19.buildFinished(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.finishBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:196)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.finishBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:132)
    at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController$1.create(GradleBuildController.java:72)
    at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService.withLocks(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:213)
    at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController.doBuild(GradleBuildController.java:67)
    at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController.run(GradleBuildController.java:56)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.AbstractClientProvidedBuildActionRunner.runClientAction(AbstractClientProvidedBuildActionRunner.java:53)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.ClientProvidedPhasedActionRunner.run(ClientProvidedPhasedActionRunner.java:47)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildOutcomeReportingBuildActionRunner.run(BuildOutcomeReportingBuildActionRunner.java:66)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ValidatingBuildActionRunner.run(ValidatingBuildActionRunner.java:32)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.FileSystemWatchingBuildActionRunner.run(FileSystemWatchingBuildActionRunner.java:90)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildCompletionNotifyingBuildActionRunner.run(BuildCompletionNotifyingBuildActionRunner.java:41)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner$3.call(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.java:49)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner$3.call(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.java:44)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:200)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:195)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$3.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:75)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$3.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:68)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:153)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:68)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.call(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:62)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.lambda$call$2(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:76)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.UnmanagedBuildOperationWrapper.callWithUnmanagedSupport(UnmanagedBuildOperationWrapper.java:54)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:76)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.run(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.java:44)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.lambda$execute$0(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:59)
    at org.gradle.composite.internal.DefaultRootBuildState.run(DefaultRootBuildState.java:86)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:58)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:30)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildTreeScopeLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.lambda$execute$0(BuildTreeScopeLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.java:34)
    at org.gradle.internal.buildtree.BuildTreeState.run(BuildTreeState.java:53)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildTreeScopeLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.execute(BuildTreeScopeLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.java:33)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildTreeScopeLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.execute(BuildTreeScopeLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.java:28)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:104)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:55)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SubscribableBuildActionExecuter.execute(SubscribableBuildActionExecuter.java:64)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SubscribableBuildActionExecuter.execute(SubscribableBuildActionExecuter.java:37)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SessionScopeLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.lambda$execute$0(SessionScopeLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.java:54)
    at org.gradle.internal.session.BuildSessionState.run(BuildSessionState.java:67)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SessionScopeLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.execute(SessionScopeLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.java:50)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SessionScopeLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.execute(SessionScopeLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.java:36)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.execute(GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.java:36)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.execute(GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.java:25)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.execute(StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.java:59)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.execute(StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.java:31)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.execute(SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.java:58)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.execute(SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.java:42)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SetupLoggingActionExecuter.execute(SetupLoggingActionExecuter.java:47)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SetupLoggingActionExecuter.execute(SetupLoggingActionExecuter.java:31)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ExecuteBuild.doBuild(ExecuteBuild.java:65)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:37)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.WatchForDisconnection.execute(WatchForDisconnection.java:39)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ResetDeprecationLogger.execute(ResetDeprecationLogger.java:29)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.execute(RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.java:35)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.create(ForwardClientInput.java:78)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.create(ForwardClientInput.java:75)
    at org.gradle.util.Swapper.swap(Swapper.java:38)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput.execute(ForwardClientInput.java:75)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogAndCheckHealth.execute(LogAndCheckHealth.java:55)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogToClient.doBuild(LogToClient.java:63)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:37)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.EstablishBuildEnvironment.doBuild(EstablishBuildEnvironment.java:84)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:37)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy$1.run(StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy.java:52)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DaemonStateCoordinator$1.run(DaemonStateCoordinator.java:297)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:48)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:56)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
```

Not sure what I have to do to fix this problem.

Here is my `gradle-wrapper.properties`

```
#Sat Jul 18 00:44:27 AEST 2020
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.0.2-all.zip
# https://services.gradle.org/distributions/
```

Here is `build.gradle` for the project level:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.5.10'
    // Import the BoM for the Firebase platform: https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/learn-more?authuser=0#bom
    ext.firebase_bom_version = '28.2.0'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.0-beta04'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.8'
        classpath "io.realm:realm-gradle-plugin:6.1.0"

        // https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/get-started?platform=android&authuser=0#add-sdk
        classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-gradle:2.7.1'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Here is `build.gradle` from one of the app:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
apply plugin: 'com.google.firebase.crashlytics'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 30
    buildToolsVersion "30.0.3"
    ndkVersion "21.3.6528147"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.abc.apps.myapp"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode 29
        versionName "6.5"
        multiDexEnabled true
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
        debug {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    buildFeatures {
        viewBinding true
    }

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation platform("com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:$firebase_bom_version")
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation project(':nextgenlib')
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.0'
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.5.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-ktx'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-ktx'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging-ktx'
}
```

I hope someone can help me.

Comment: Reverting `com.google.gms:google-services` to 4.3.5 worked for me as a temporary workaround.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

https://docs.gradle.org/6.8/userguide/upgrading_version_6.html#querying_a_mapped_output_property_of_a_task_before_the_task_has_completed

> Querying the value of a mapped output property before the task has completed can cause strange build failures because it indicates stale or non-existent outputs may be used by mistake. This behavior is deprecated and will emit a deprecation warning. This will become an error in Gradle 7.0.
>
> The following example demonstrates this problem where the Producer’s output file is parsed before the Producer executes:
>
> ```
> class Consumer extends DefaultTask {
>    @Input
>     final Property<Integer> threadPoolSize = ...
> }
>
> class Producer extends DefaultTask {
>     @OutputFile
>     final RegularFileProperty outputFile = ...
> }
>
> // threadPoolSize is read from the producer's outputFile
> consumer.threadPoolSize = producer.outputFile.map { it.text.toInteger() }
>
> // Emits deprecation warning
> println("thread pool size = " + consumer.threadPoolSize.get())
> ```
>
> Querying the value of `consumer.threadPoolSize` will produce a deprecation warning if done prior to producer completing, as the output file has not yet been generated.

Comment: I still don't understand. I'm also having this error but I don't know which lines are causing it. Can it be fixed or it is an error from plugin?

Comment: @gumil yeah, this is so confused, right? It won't show you exactly the what is the line you made this mistake. I said `Querying the value of a mapped output property before the task has completed can cause strange build failures`.  `strange build failures` are really confused. but probably we did query the value of a mapped output before the task has completed. I'm still trying to find it in my codes :(

Comment: I don't get it, is there any fix? or shall we downgrade to a lower version?

Comment: @ArashAfsharpour The fix is to scan through your code where you're trying to access the value of mapped output property while the task may not be completed. I know this sounds very general, but you have to do that. Downgrade is not a solution, it will be unsupported some days soon.

Comment: To be clear. I finally found out where in my code and fixed it. The above `general` solution is actually working great, it's just hard to find out where it is in your code if you don't understand fully your code.

Comment: mac users: `brew install gradle@6`

Comment: @DanielsaysReinstateMonica that is running away from the problem by downgrading the gradle, not actually fixing it. I understand that with some complex project/system, it's hard to find the root cause with this general error, but it's still a problem. I'm so lucky that my project is not that big and I was able to find out what was the problem. Hope you can do it as well. Running away is not a solution though.

Answer (score 223):

Under projects build.gradle file

update the `com.google.gms:google-services` to version `4.3.14`.

```
 dependencies {
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.14'
}
```

Comment: Did not work for me

Comment: 4.3.10 -> 4.3.15 take me one further step on refactoring, stackoverflow, my hero.

Comment: This just worked for me (in my case I was working in a Flutter project, but the issue was the same).

Comment: Thank you so much. It helped.
My case is upgrading React Native 0.68 to fit Android SDK 33 and corresponding changes for a  release build.
I had to upgrade the Gradle (distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.5.1-all.zip) and faced this error.

Comment: Updating the library fixed the issue. Thanks

Answer (score 44):

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.10'
```

it was not working for me
I did simply use the below code:

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.14'
```

Comment: using :  `classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.15'`, plus :     `implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:24.5.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:21.3.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:20.0.1'` worked for me

Answer (score 33):

In most cases, it's an incompatibility issue between Gradle & Android Gradle Plugin.

**Gradle**: `x.x.x`

**AGP**: `y.y.y`

Play with these versions to find a proper match.

As for now, in my case works

> classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.2.2'
>
> Gradle 7.4

Comment: You can easily change it in Android Studio via File > Project Structure. This will open Project Structure window. Then just make sure you're in the "Project" tab in the window.

Comment: Thank you, this did work while other combinations didn't.

Comment: Use Tools > AGP Upgrade Assistant in the latest Android Studio to change the AGP to the latest.   Gradle version 8.0 and AGP version 8.1.1 solve my problem

Answer (score 6):

Also experiencing this issue after adding Google Play Services and Firebase as seen in your build.gradle to a practically empty Compose template project. Same error when using AGP 7.3.0-alpha05.

Reverting to AGP 7.1.2 and Gradle 7.4 resolved this for me. There may be compatibility issue within the Google services plugin and AGP to be resolved.

Comment: Reverting isn't an option as the old version will be deprecated soon. The best way is still to find where it is in your code, that you're trying to access the value of mapped output property while the task may not be completed, and fix it. For my project, I did it myself, so I fully understand my code and I finally found and fixed it without reverting to old version.

Comment: Updating my gms dependency to the latest version (`com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.14`) worked for me

Answer (score 3):

Likely a cache issue. Run this command for fixing the problem.

```
./gradlew clean assembleDebug
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried and it didn't work. `./gradew clean assembleDebug` doesn't show that warning in the console. But Android Studio is still showing it in Sync tab.

Comment: After searching and finding everywhere, found the answer from the documentation. See above accepted answer from myself.

Comment: You are right. It is showing the real error

Answer (score 3):

- update the com.google.gms:google-services to version 4.3.14 work
- update the com.google.gms:google-services to newest version 4.4.0
  work too

Answer (score 2):

I fixed this error by upgrading the following in the project build.gradle to their latest version:

```
com.android.tools.build:gradle:(latest version)
com.google.gms:google-services:(latest version)
org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:(latest version)
```

Answer (score 2):

If your facing in Android Studio Flamingo or any other Version than follow the below steps.

First Step : Update Your ClassPath to as following

```
    dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.2'
    }
```

Second Step: Check your JDK Version, it must be a **11.0.20**

Third Step : check your **gradle-wrapper.properties** file, your gradle version must be like below.

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.2-bin.zip
```

I hope this will work for you.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to bypass this problem then you can disable inverse mapping task (see example). But after that you should really check if it's ok by you and if there is no problem with your app.

**example usage:**

We have these flavors in our app:

- developmentDebug
- developmentRelease
- productionDebug
- productionRelease

Now I want to build app bundle for **productionRelease** variant. As I told earlier you need to disable inverse task for mapping => map**ProductionDebug**SourceSetPaths.

```
tasks.whenTaskAdded {
    if(this.name.contains("mapProductionDebugSourceSetPaths")) {
        this.enabled = false
    }
}
```

After this step appBundle is finally buildable (AS dolphin 7, AGP 7.3.0-alpha07). Why it needs to be inverse is beyond me.

Comment: I don't think bypass this is a solution. Bypassing the warning is actually trying to swallow a potential bug. Just fix it instead of bypassing is better. I actually fixed them all in my projects. I know it's hard to some people to fix it as the warning message is unclear, but if you understand code in your project, I'm pretty you can fix it.

Answer (score 0):

please check that your project-level gradle (`android/build.gradle`) matches your app-level gradle (`gradle-wrapper.properties`) [here](https://developer.android.com/build/releases/gradle-plugin#updating-gradle)

I had app-level at 7.0.3, with project-level set to 4.0.1 and it was giving me this issue. I fixed it by putting project-level (`android/build.gradle`) at 7.0.0.

Answer (score -9):

Make sure that path of JDK_HOME is correct

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).